# Autostart Activitywatch - 16.04

Tags: 16.04, boot, autostart

I was trying to autostart ActivityWatch . Made a `activitywatch.service` file in `/etc/systemd/system` .

```
[Unit]
Description=Activity Watch
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=%i
ExecStart=/home/anoopd/venv/bin/aw-qt -c "~/.config/activitywatch"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Reloaded systemed
`sudo systemctl --system daemon-reload`

To start automatically at boot:

```
sudo systemctl enable activitywatch
```

To start it now:

```
sudo systemctl start activitywatch
```

When I checked the status:

```
$ sudo systemctl status activitywatch
● activitywatch.service - Activity Watch
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/activitywatch.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2018-09-06 09:13:10 IST; 25min ago
Process: 11013 ExecStart=/home/anoopd/venv/bin/aw-qt -c ~/.config/activitywatch (code=exited, status=2)
Main PID: 11013 (code=exited, status=2)

Sep 06 09:13:08 anoops-ubuntu systemd[1]: Started Activity Watch.
Sep 06 09:13:09 anoops-ubuntu aw-qt[11013]: usage: aw-qt [-h] [--testing] [--autostart-modules AUTOSTART_MODULES]
Sep 06 09:13:09 anoops-ubuntu aw-qt[11013]: aw-qt: error: unrecognized arguments: -c ~/.config/activitywatch
Sep 06 09:13:10 anoops-ubuntu systemd[1]: activitywatch.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
Sep 06 09:13:10 anoops-ubuntu systemd[1]: activitywatch.service: Unit entered failed state.
Sep 06 09:13:10 anoops-ubuntu systemd[1]: activitywatch.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I am not sure about the `INVALIDARGUMENT` . Please help .

**Edit**

I completely removed the `-c` param from `ExecStart` and now the status is giving the error:

```
● activitywatch.service - Activity Watch
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/activitywatch.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2018-09-06 09:54:13 IST; 5s ago
Process: 15036 ExecStart=/home/anoopd/venv/bin/aw-qt (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Main PID: 15036 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Sep 06 09:54:13 anoops-ubuntu aw-qt[15036]:   File "/home/anoopd/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/aw_qt/manager.py", line 149, in autostart
Sep 06 09:54:13 anoops-ubuntu aw-qt[15036]:     self.start("aw-server")
Sep 06 09:54:13 anoops-ubuntu aw-qt[15036]:   File "/home/anoopd/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/aw_qt/manager.py", line 142, in start
Sep 06 09:54:13 anoops-ubuntu aw-qt[15036]:     self.modules[module_name].start()
Sep 06 09:54:13 anoops-ubuntu aw-qt[15036]:   File "/home/anoopd/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/aw_qt/manager.py", line 50, in start
Sep 06 09:54:13 anoops-ubuntu aw-qt[15036]:     os.setpgrp()
Sep 06 09:54:13 anoops-ubuntu aw-qt[15036]: PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
Sep 06 09:54:13 anoops-ubuntu systemd[1]: activitywatch.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 06 09:54:13 anoops-ubuntu systemd[1]: activitywatch.service: Unit entered failed state.
```

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you figure it out?

Comment: It says "Operation not permitted" - have you tried running it with root privileges? What happens if you run it manually in the command-line?

Answer (score 0):

Can be done manually by adding `aw-qt` in the Startup Applications.

[image: aw-qt executable]

Reference: [ActivityWatch / activitywatch  Document how to autostart for all platforms #116](https://github.com/ActivityWatch/activitywatch/issues/116)